# Retrieving list of ids

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm looking to retrieve a list of integer values through SqlAlchemy. Let's say I have a model (and table) named `Element`, that have an `id` attribute. I'm trying to figure out a way to get a single list of ids without any client-side processing..

Currently I have something like:

`mylist = [o.id for o in session.query(Element).all()]`

I've been able to get a list of tuples using `session.query(Element.id)`, but that's not exactly what I'm looking for as it returns `[(1,),(2,)]` and I'm looking for `[1,2,3]`.

Answer (score 2):

This might work, if that's your output:

```
mylist = map(lambda element: element.id[0], session.query(Element).all())
```

Comment: Yeah, that would probably give me the result that I'm looking for (same as my code above).. I'm just wondering if there's a way to do it *without* duplicating the list by doing it natively in the SQLAlchemy query. I know I could use a generator post query to iterate over the list, but hate writing non-DRY code ;)

Comment: Here is a generator version: (v[0] for v in Element.query.values(Element.id))

Comment: @alexvasi: I'm just playing with `lambda`s :P I've never had this problem, though, so I can't see why SQLAlchemy isn't cooperating.

Comment: @alexvasi: I'm aware of that.. I'm wondering if it's functionality exposed natively by SQLAlchemy.